# Using session variables in ASP Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I want to fill a combo box located in the top menu; the menu is in the file _layout.cshtml and I don't want to fill from every action I call in my application.

There is a way to fill the combo using a session variable from the razor view?

Thanks

Comment: You mean you don't want to retrieve the items from the database or other location again? I don't see what this has to do with Razor.

Comment: Look in the docs for "ViewComponent" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and assumes a lot, Do you need to even store the values, can you just add a select list?

```
<select>
<option value="1">option 1</option>
<option value="2">option 2</option>
<option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```